# Go back react router, and detect if the history have no items to hide the button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to make a button for going back, I did the following:

```js
const GoBackBtn = ()=>{
   const navigate = useNavigate()
   return (<button onClick={()=>navigate(-1)}> {'<='} </button>)
}
```

It works great, however, the problem is when I first visit the webpage where this component is placed on and I'm in the root:

http://localhost:3000/

the problem which happens is when you click on the button, it takes you out of the website to the blank page (the browser home page, if you're using chrome, the home page of chrome).

I want to prevent that by hiding the button if there were no items in the history of the router.

But how I can detect that?

- React router v6
- React v18

I want to keep this functionality only on my website, I don't want it to navigate outside my website or to others websites

Comment: It's poor UX to "trap" users in your web page/app. They should be able to freely navigate back as far as the browser will let them. Any back buttons you are rendering in the app should mirror the same behavior of the Browser's back button. I don't recommend doing this, but ***if you absolutely must*** have this behavior then you will need to keep and maintain your own in-app history stack and check the top of the stack for entries.

Comment: you can use history object of window. history.length will help you

Comment: @AykhanHuseyn, I saw it, but it's hard to tell if it's accurate

Comment: @DrewReese, can I know which url the `useNavigate()()` (with the two braces) is going to navigate to next? i.e `navigate()`

Comment: It'd be trivial to try, but I suspect one or both of 2 things will happen: (1) an invariant warning about the `to` argument being undefined, and (2) warning about navigating as an unexpected side-effect since the `navigate` function wasn't invoked as a regular part of the component lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

React Router has a hook called `useLocation`. Using this hook, you can get the path of the current route. The path for the root route is `/`.

I would add the condition such as:

```
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

const goBackBtn = () => {
  const location = useLocation()
  const navigate = useNavigate()

  const goBack = () => {
    if (location.pathname !== '/') {
      navigate(-1)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {location.pathname !== '/' && (
        <button onClick={goBack}>
          {'<='}
        </button>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: yes but what if the first page the user was landed on was /users/902390402, in this case if the user pressed, he will be kicked out of the website, this only solves the problem if the user was first landed on `/`

Comment: If the root path is not `/`, you should know the current user and the root path for the current user. Then, you can change the condition like:


```
location.pathname !== `/users/${currentUser.rootPath}`
```


Or. if you know that `/users/${id}` is the root path for each user:


```
location.pathname !== `/users/${currentUser.id}`
```